# simple question on circuits

Tags: voltage, resistors, series

[image]

This is a simple question on impedance and i just need to make sure i know the correct answer

Comment: What did you calculate?

Comment: i calculated '3' ?

Comment: That's the wrong answer so what formula did you use. Feel free to find the formula using google.

Comment: Google the formula. Then plug the numbers in. This is help.

Comment: This should be be trivial.  We can help but the formula should be in any good text book or findable with Google. Clue: it will contain \$ \omega \$ or \$ f \$.  We don't just do homework for you.  Show us what you have tried.  Formula used and calculation.  This should be in your question, not a comment.

Comment: i used 1/ 2 (by)fc and got 15.915 kohm

Comment: @Warren Hill It's trivial if you have a relevant degree. We were all beginners at some point.

Comment: All we were asking is to see your effort.

Answer (score -5, accepted):

Well, we know:

$$\underline{\text{Z}}_\text{C}=\frac{1}{\text{j}\omega\text{C}}\tag1$$

And the reactance is given by:

$$\text{X}_\text{C}=\left|\frac{1}{\text{j}\omega\text{C}}\right|=\frac{1}{\left|\text{j}\omega\text{C}\right|}=\frac{1}{\omega\text{C}}\tag2$$

So, we get:

$$\text{X}_\text{C}=\frac{1}{2\pi\cdot1000\cdot0.01\cdot10^{-6}}=\frac{50000}{\pi}\approx15915.5\space\Omega\tag3$$

Which gives:

$$\text{X}_\text{C}\approx15.9155\space\text{k}\Omega\tag4$$

Comment: Whilst your answer is technically correct (arguably the best sort of correct) and beautifully formatted I suspect it's being downvoted because this is a homework question. Ahmed is best helped by being guided to solve this himself rather than just giving him the answer.